# DOM manip blocked by long-running func invoked *afterwards*?

Tags: javascript, dom, blocking

Simple question.

What's so special about the DOM that manipulating it is blocked by long-running javascript functions invoked *after* the DOM manipulation calls? Here's an example:

```
function notify(msg) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.textContent = msg;
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}

// long-running func
function block() {
  var iter = 3e8;

  while (iter--)
    Math.sqrt(iter);

  notify("block() done!");
}

document.body.onclick = function(){
  notify("click event!");
  block();
};
```

both, *click event!* and *block() done!* appear simultaneously after the long-running function exits rather than *click event!* triggering immediately and *block() done!* appearing later.

here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bxuNb/1/

if *notify("click event!");* is replaced with *alert("click event!");*, then it responds instantly. what's going on here?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's so special about the DOM that manipulating it is blocked by javascript functions

It's optimized. Your screen won't be repainted after every single interaction with the DOM.

> …invoked after the DOM manipulation calls

It can't be known that there is no further DOM manipulation ahead in the execution - therefore it doesn't update your screen right away. Even while that would be possible by static code analysis, there *is* another DOM manipulation in your example. The interpreter just can't know that the few lines of code in between will take that long to execute.

If you want to allow the screen to update in between, start the long-running block with a timeout after your first output:

```
document.body.onclick = function(){
  notify("click event!");
  setTimeout(block, 0);
};
```

Comment: the problem in my particular case is that i have a long-running function that needs those elements in the DOM. With setTimeout/0, the DOM gets updated, but the function is not guaranteed to have all nodes present there prior to execution. one example is using getComputedStyle in Chrome, which only works after DOM insertion.

Comment: Well the elements *are* in the DOM, only the screen is not updated. `getComputedStyle` would force a reflow which leads to a repaint.